# Plot not updating on shiny server when data is refreshed

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm having trouble deploying a shiny app to shiny server.

Basically, I have a CSV that updates every morning and I'd like for the shiny app on the server to check if there's been a refresh every five minutes and reactively edit the data and display the plot below.

This data munging (`create_issue_spotter_data`) takes a relatively long time in R, so I also have a slightly sketchy way of making sure this data refresh does not happen when a new session begins: I have a `start` variable that checks if it's equal to 1. If it is, it increments so the next time `chat_file()` is updated, the `create_issue_spotter_data` function will be called. I'm open to completely removing this if it's poor practice.

When this app is running locally, it works exactly how I want it. However, it does not work on shiny server. The code is posted below:

```
write.csv(mtcars, 'mtcars.csv')

create_issue_spotter_data = function(df) {
 df$new_column = 0
 df = df[df$mpg < 20, ]
 return(df)
}



ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(align = "center", downloadButton("download_btn")),
  fluidRow(align = "center", plotOutput("distPlot"))

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  start <- 1

  file <- reactiveFileReader(
    intervalMillis = 1000 * 60 * 5, 
    session = NULL, 
    filePath = 'mtcars.csv', 
    readFunc = readr::read_csv
  )

  this_df = eventReactive(file(), {
    if (start != 1) {
      print(paste("Now updating the data. Date:", Sys.time()))
      saved_df <<- create_issue_spotter_data(file())
      df <- saved_df
    } else {
      start <<- start + 1
      print(paste("Everything's good at", Sys.time()))
      df <- saved_df
    }
    df
  })

  output$download_btn <- downloadHandler(
    filename = paste0(paste("Issue", "Spotter", gsub("-", "_", Sys.Date()), sep = "_"), ".pdf"),
    content = function(file) {
    pdf(file)
    p = build_cluster_viz(this_df(), download = TRUE)
    print(p)
    dev.off()
  }, contentType = "pdf")

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(this_df()$mpg, this_df()$disp)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for making your data reproducible! What is your error when you run it in shiny-server?

Comment: @divibisan Basically the plot is not registering that the data has been changed. Something that I noticed that I can't really explain why is when I'm doing something locally, my app is open and therefore updates the changes. However, on the shiny-server, since the app may not be open for hours, it will not register that the data file has changed therefore telling the plot to change as well. I'm trying to get my app to see that there's been a change, but also not re-run the update when someone goes onto the app because the actual `create_issue_date_spotter` takes about an hour.

Comment: Could you move the `create_issue_date_spotter` function completely out of the shiny app? For example, have a cron job run a separate script every day that checks for changes and runs `create_issue_date_spotter` if needed. That would simplify your problem, I think, and would let you update the dataset in the background without hanging the shiny app for an hour while the function runs

Comment: @divibisan that could work. What would you suggest for storing the dataset and calling it from R?